# How to create different answers depending on an entity value in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

Assume I have an entity called *Animal* with values *Dog*, *Cat*, *Fish*, *Parrot*

I would like the bot to answer to:

*How long does @Animal live?*

*How many legs does @Animal have?*

*Does @Animal fly?*
etc.

I am trying to create a table of values associated with each of the Animal.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option here is to create one intent per question you want to answer.

So, given your examples

### 1) Animal - life expectancy

**Training phrases**

```
@ - How long does @Animal:Animal live?
@ - How many years do @Animal:Animal live?
@ - @Animal life expectancy
" - How long do elephants live
```

**Webhook answer**

```
Elephants can live up to 70 years in the wild
```

---

### 2) Animal - Legs

**Training phrases**

```
" - How many legs does dogs have?
@ - How many legs does @Animal have?
@ - leg count of @Animal
```

**Webhook answer**

```
Dogs have 4 legs.
```

---

### 3) Animal - Fly

**Training phrases**

```
@ - Does @Animal fly?
" - Can cats fly?
```

**Webhook answer**

```
No, cats can't fly.
```

---

**Entity**

[image]

---

**Intent**

[image]

**Legend:**

```
 " - example mode
 @ - Template mode
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I understand that I need to create a webhook, that is a web service on another server. There is no way to associate somehow with the different type of Animals. For example, for the legs, I want to associate Dog = 4, Cat = 4, Fish = 0, Parrot = 2

Comment: Oh I see, there's a work around, which I won't recommend, the best way is to use a webhook.

Comment: thank you. Just out of curiosity, what is the workaround?